# Is DotNetNuke solid application development framework?

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I am considering creating e-learning SaaS solution so therefore I am evaluating using application development framework like DotNetNuke as a base. I would have loved to use Salesforce Force.com platform but unfortunately it is quite expensive.

The biggest advantage of using stable and solid development framework is that I won't have to concern myself with architectural issues and can concentrate solely on core functionality. Another advantage of using DotNetNuke is that some of the functionality I require like forums, content and user management is already implemented.

Is it worth using DotNetNuke as a development framework so as to avoid dealing with scalability?

If anyone else has been in this situation I would love to hear what you decided on.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was involved with one project where the vendor using it was happy with it.
They did tend to do smaller scale stuff - so don't take their say-so if you want to use it for large-scale stuff; your mileage may vary.

Also, I've asked various people the same question.  Of those with first hand experience roughly 3 or 4 out of 5 hated it.  Still "one mans rubbish is another mans gold", as the saying goes.

Comment: Why do so many developers hate DotNetNuke?

Comment: You do have to admit it does have a reasonably large following - so it can't be all bad.  Why do people love/hate anything? Here's one reason: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for a CMS, I would recommend Umbraco (http://www.umbraco.com)
I use is since it uses real asp.net masterpages and allows using .net usercontrols.
It is the only CMS I have tried that allowed me to go from HTML and CSS to a fully working site, without conforming to a preset template.

Edit: And it's free :)